# Python - Add dummy parameter to function signature

Tags: python, function

I have a function:

```py
def dummy_func(a, b: float, c: int = 1) -> float:
    #some code
```

I want to write a generic functor (`dummy_prepender`) that would take the function and construct a new one wose only difference from the original is  that an extra unused parameter is prepended to signature:

```py
dummy_method1 = dummy_prepender(dummy_func)

#dummy_method1 should behave exactly like the following code:

def dummy_method(dummy, a, b: float, c: int = 1) -> float:
    #some code
```

so that for any set of arguments and dummy_arg

`dummy_method(dummy_arg, arguments...)` behave **exactly the same** as `dummy_func(arguments...)`.

I thought that `@staticmethod` would do the trick, but there are places where the dispatch happens differently and applying staticmethod has no effect.

Some behavior tests:

`help(dummy_method)` should show the correct signature

`dummy_method(dummy='', a=1)` should fail

`dummy_method(dummy='', a=1, b=2, c=3, z=4)` should fail

**Update**:

Here is an example of `staticmethod` not working as expected:

Example 1

```
factory_type = type('Typ1', (), {
    '__init__': staticmethod(dummy_func),
})

inspect.signature(factory_type)

#<Signature (b:float, c:int=1) -> float>
#BTW, in this case it's just the inspect.signature that is broken. The call behavior seems to be correct
```

Example 2:

```
factory_type2 = type('Typ1', (), {
    '__new__': staticmethod(dummy_func),
})

#Call behavior is broken
factory_type2(a=1, b=2)
# TypeError: dummy_func() got multiple values for argument 'a'

factory_type2(7, 13)
# locals()={'c': 13, 'b': 7, 'a': <class '__main__.Typ1'>}
# See how the class got passed as `a` instead of `dummy`
```

The result of `staticmethod(func)` is not a function, but a descriptor object. And sometimes the behavior is not the same.

Comment: And what doesn't work with what you have can you explain how `there are places where the dispatch happens differently`

Comment: @devesh-kumar-singh Added an example

Comment: Can you tell me the idea behind this exercise, do you want `dummy_method` to be a wrapper around `dummy_func`

Comment: My low-level goal is: Given a normal function, construct a type where the function serves as the implementation of the `__new__` or `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be something like this:

```
def dummy_method(*args, **kwargs) -> float:
    return dummy_func(*args[1:], **kwargs)
```

The upcoming Python 3.8 implements [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/), which allows the following syntax:

```
# 'dummy' is a positional only argument, disallowing 'dummy=...'
def dummy_method(dummy, /, *args, **kwargs) -> float:
    return dummy_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here another version for Python 3.8, which keeps the signature:

```
def dummy_method(dummy, /, a, b: float, c: int = 1) -> float:
    return dummy_func(a, b, c)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it does not preserve or enforce the original signature. There are some requirements listed in the "Some behavior tests" section of the question.

Comment: @Ark-kun True, I missed that. It looks like you have to wait for Python 3.8 to make the `dummy` paramter positional only.

Comment: I can already make a function with augmented signature by re-creating the FunctionType from `co_code` etc, but I thought that there might be some existing option. Like `staticmethod`, anti-`partial` or `func.get(...)`.